# Making Glue delete source data after a job

Tags: bigdata, etl, aws-glue

AWS Glue is great for transforming data from a raw form into whichever format you need, and keeping the source and destination data sets synchronized.

However, I have a scenario where data lands in a 'landing area' bucket from untrusted external sources, and the first ETL step needs to be a data validation step which only allows valid data to pass to the data lake, while non-valid data is moved to a quarantine bucket for manual inspection.

Non-valid data includes:

- bad file formats/encodings
- unparseable contents
- mismatched schemas
- even some sanity checks on the data itself

The 'landing area' bucket is not part of the data lake, it is only a temporary dead drop for incoming data, and so I need the validation job to delete the files from this bucket once it has moved them to the lake and/or quarantine buckets.

Is this possible with Glue? If the data is deleted from the source bucket, won't Glue end up removing it downstream in a subsequent update?

Am I going to need a different tool (e.g. StreamSets, NiFi, or Step Functions with AWS Batch) for this validation step, and only use Glue once the data is in the lake?

(I know I can set lifecycle rules on the bucket itself to delete the data after a certain time, like 24 hours, but in theory this could delete data before Glue has processed it, e.g. in case of a problem with the Glue job)

Answer (score 7):

Please see purge_s3_path in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html):

```
glueContext.purge_s3_path(s3_path, options={}, transformation_ctx="")
```

> Deletes files from the specified Amazon S3 path recursively.

Also, make sure your `AWSGlueServiceRole` has `s3:DeleteObject` permissions

Answer (score 0):

Your glue environment comes with boto3. You should be better of using the boto3 s3 client/resource  to delete the landing files after Youve completed processing the data via glue

Comment: For the example above, I assume that there is some pattern match for all incoming files.  If this is the case and there are multiple files going through validation, how do you determine the bucket/key names of each file to feed into boto3?